# Can I add user data information to the token?

Tags: fusionauth

Roles etc get persisted to the token. Is it possible to add the user data to it? Or get the user data returned from the oauth2/userinfo call? Otherwise I have to do 2 calls when validating the token as I need a value in the user data.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jwt.io/, here you can add any userdata encryped to the token

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to FusionAuth due to the `fusionauth` tag.

In FusionAuth, it is not currently possible to add custom claims or additional free form data stored in the user data field to the signed token.

This feature is coming soon. Here is the existing feature request.  https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/61

Hopefully Q2 of 2019.

***Update as of 2/10/2019***

We are shipping lambda support in version `1.6.0`, due out any day now. One of the initial uses of the lambda will be for adding additional claims to the JWT. This feature will allow any data found in User object to be added to the JWT before it is signed. This feature is being tracked in the above linked GitHub issue.